# How to parametrise a single Cucumber API test Scenario with Multiple Json request in KARATE framework

Tags: rest, selenium, cucumber, karate, web-api-testing

As of now, I have a single cucumber scenario which runs with a json file with single API request. I want to run the same scenario for multiple API request using same json. So I can verify multiple api test.

@Test1

Feature: Test_Multiple_API_Karate

Scenario: Exe - Individual Rule

```
* url restBaseApi
* configure headers = read('classpath:headers.js')
* def caseRequest = read('../data/caseRequest.json')
* def caseExpectedResponse = read('../data/caseExpectedResponse.json')


Given path ‘case-Karate-request’
And request caseRequest[i]
When method POST
Then status 200
Then print response
And match response == caseExpectedResponse[i]
```

We need to run karate request with caseRequest.json (as mentioned below)

[
{
"srId": "1-2A1”,
"process": “Information”,
"area": “Software”,
"subArea": “Technical”,
"status": “Open”
},
{
"srId": “1-2A2”,
"process": “Manufacture”,
"area": “Software”,
"subArea": “SAP”,
"status": “Closed”
}
]

How to run this scenario with the test data for both request in single execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look into the documentation for [Data Driven Scenarios](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests)

```
@Test1

Feature: Test_Multiple_API_Karate

Background: 
* def caseRequest = read('../data/caseRequest.json')
* def caseExpectedResponse = read('../data/caseExpectedResponse.json')

Scenario Outline: Exe - Individual Rule

* url restBaseApi
* configure headers = read('classpath:headers.js')


Given path ‘case-Karate-request’
And request __row
When method POST
Then status 200
Then print response
And match response == caseExpectedResponse[__num]
Examples:
|caseRequest|
```

I also suggest you merge both JSON array into the singe JSON to avoid any confusion on index while altering